# Sort() not working

Tags: sorting, vue.js, axios

I'm having an issue with the sort() in ranking data from coinmarketcap api. With an ajax api call, sort works in returning an array with the right ranking. With an axios api call, seen below, it doesn't.

Here is my code using axios and vue.js:

```
let coinMarket = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10'
let updateInterval = 60 * 1000;

let newApp = new Vue({
  el: '#coinApp',
  data: {
    // data within an array
    results: []
},
  methods: {
    getCoins: function() {
        axios
            .get(coinMarket)
            .then((resp) => {
              this.results = formatCoins(resp);
            });
    },

    getColor: (num) => {
        return num > 0 ? "color:green;" : "color:red;";
    },
},
    created: function() {
        this.getCoins();
    }
})
setInterval(() => {
        newApp.getCoins();
    },
    updateInterval
);
function formatCoins(res) {
    var coinDataArray = []
    Object.keys(res.data).forEach(function(key) {
        coinDataArray.push(res.data[key])
    })
    coinDataArray.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.rank > b.rank
    })
    console.log(coinDataArray)
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The correct way for sorting in ascending order is `a.rank - b.rank` check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Hi, I have tried that but the results are the same.

Comment: How does your data look like? make sure your `rank` values are numbers

Comment: The rank data are numbers. I'm really scratching my head over.

Comment: could you please post your `coinDataArray` content?

Comment: it should be `Object.keys(res.data.data).forEach(function(key) {
      
        coinDataArray.push(res.data.data[key])
    })
    coinDataArray.sort(function(a,b) {
        return b.rank - a.rank
    })`, not `res.data`

Comment: Thanks so much - it's working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the data responded by `https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10`, you will find the data you need is under `res.data.data`, not `res.data`.

So within the function=**formatCoins**, replace `res.data` with `res.data.data`, then works.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
let coinMarket = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10'
let updateInterval = 60 * 1000;

function formatCoins(res) {
    var coinDataArray = []
    Object.keys(res.data.data).forEach(function(key) {
      
        coinDataArray.push(res.data.data[key])
    })
    coinDataArray.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.rank - b.rank
    })

    return coinDataArray
}

let newApp = new Vue({
  el: '#coinApp',
  data: {
    // data within an array
    results: []
  },
  methods: {
    getCoins: function() {
        axios
            .get(coinMarket)
            .then((resp) => {
              this.results = formatCoins(resp);
            });
    },

    getColor: (num) => {
        return num > 0 ? "color:green;" : "color:red;";
    },
  },
  created: function() {
      this.getCoins();
  }
})
setInterval(() => {
        newApp.getCoins();
    },
    updateInterval
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="coinApp">
    <div v-for="(record, index) in results" :key="index">
      {{index}} - {{record.name}}: {{record.rank}}
    </div>
</div>
```